# Format Datetime class to '2013-08-05T10:00:00 '

Tags: php, datetime

I am using Datetime class on PHP.

you can change datetimeclass to string like this.

```
$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
// it shows 2013-08-05 10:00:00
```

but somehow ,Google API requires format like this .

```
2013-08-05T10:00:00
```

What this T means ?

and How can I make this style string from DateTime class neatly?

Comment: The `T` is just a date/time delimiter (it was probably chosen in order to avoid ambiguities when it comes to whitespace characters). I am not quite sure if it actually stands for anything, though "Time" would make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time is in [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.  [To print it out, you can use `'c'` format character:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

```
$date->format('c')
```

Comment: wow thanks had no idea about that .. ill delete the comments from above +1 lol

Comment: You can also use the constant `DATE_ISO8601`, or the class constant `DateTime::ISO8601`. They are a little more self-explanatory than just `c` (which is helpful for when you come back to the code later).

Comment: Thanks, I have new knowledge now.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [jh314's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18118049/1438393) solution above, and it will give you the time in following format:

```
2013-08-08T10:18:15+05:30
```

However, to format it exactly like you want, you could use the following:

```
$part1 = $date->format('Y-m-d');  // 2013-08-08
$part2 = $date->format('H:i:s');  // 10:19:37
$newdate = "{$part1}T{$part2}";   // 2013-08-08T10:19:37
```

Or better yet:

```
$date = $date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s'); // 2013-08-08T10:19:37
```

[**Ta-dah!**](http://codepad.org/et5zr3Qs)

Comment: Why do it in two parts? You can escape the `T` character, like `Y-m-d\TH:i:s`.

Answer (score 0):

This is ISO 8601 datetime format [check this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

```
$date->format('c')   //Output 2004-02-12T15:19:21+00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

This is almost, but not quite ISO8601 format, so you need to format the output like this:-

```
$date = new \DateTime();
echo $date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');
```

The `\` escapes the 'T'. See [the manual](http://php.net/date) about formatting dates.

[See it working](http://3v4l.org/Dvcfd)